# Spring MVC java annotation configuration process

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In spring-mvc , after tomcat server is started which component of spring-mvc loads the configuration files ? 
for eg. initializer and etc.

Comment: In a Spring Boot application or "plain" Spring?

Comment: "plain" Spring mvc

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking for. There are two Classes that are fired up at spring start: ContextLoaderListener and later on the DispatcherServlet